# Build an angular image that recompile always when source code change

Tags: angular, docker

I'm trying to dockerize an Angular App for Dev mode.

So I want to have my source code in my machine and create a container that read my source code folder realtime if I do changes.

If Dokcer is not supporting this or is low performance for this job, please tell me.

#DockerFile

```
FROM node:latest
LABEL author="Karim"
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
WORKDIR /var/www/angular-app
ENTRYPOINT ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

#Run

```
> docker run -t -p 1000:4200 -v "C:\Users\k.garali\Desktop\Docker\angular-app-image/angular-app":/var/www/angular-app angular-image
```

output:

The Angular App compiles and I see the app in my browser OK, but when I edit my source code, that didn't recompile :(

I try also removing ENTRYPOINT from DockerFile
and instead running it into the bash directly to be able to check if it recompile or not :

```
> docker exec -i -t <my_container> /bin/bash

# ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

But I got the same thing, the App compiles just once, and I have to stop and rerun the container to get the changes.

Any clarification ?

Comment: File change notifications between host and container don't work on all platforms.

Comment: So do you think I'm using docker in the wrong way ?

Comment: No, this is just an implementation restriction (e.g. on Windows). Your setup would perfectly work on Linux.

Comment: To work around this, you could run a bash in the container and start ng serve manually. This is slightly more convenient because you do not need to restart the whole container, but just ng serve.

Comment: Thank you But here I'am trying to set up a system full performance. If I stop manually ng serve in every change, That's not acceptable in dev mode.

Comment: Plain Node can do this just fine, and doesn't require the additional steps of setting up Docker.  For an Angular application, since the application itself runs in the browser, it can't take advantage of most of Docker's features (you can't use container names as host names for example).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a windows related issue, when I did some research I found this [repository](https://github.com/merofeev/docker-windows-volume-watcher).

```
The script aims to be workaround for the problem of file change events propagation on Windows hosts.   
Due to limitations of CIFS implementation in Linux kernel, file change events in mounted folders of host are not propagated to container by Docker for Windows.  
This problem renders watch mode of modern frameworks (e.g. Jekyll, ng-cli, etc.) development servers useless, since containers are not notified about file changes.
```

On a side note: I would personally just run the ng dev server from the command line / or your ide during development.